# making a browser-action mimic a server request

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I am not quite sure how to correctly phrase the title of this question but here goes… my app is all client-side, all the logic embedded in the web page, and nothing on the server except a simple web server. And I want to keep it that way.

Now, I have a few panels in my webpage that I are hidden by default.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│       https://server/home       │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│                                 │
│   about   privacy   contact     │
│                                 │
│  ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─      │
│             about         │     │
│  │                              │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘     │
│  ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─      │
│             privacy       │     │
│  │                              │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘     │
│  ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─      │
│             contact       │     │
│  │                              │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘     │
│                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

When the user clicks on any of the links – about, privacy, contact – then the respective panel becomes visible and the URL in the browser bar changes to reflect the state with the help of `history.pushState()`. So far so good.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│      https://server/about       │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│                                 │
│   about   privacy   contact     │
│                                 │
│  ┌────────────────────────┐     │
│  │          about         │     │
│  │                        │     │
│  └────────────────────────┘     │
│  ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─      │
│             privacy       │     │
│  │                              │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘     │
│  ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─      │
│             contact       │     │
│  │                              │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘     │
│                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now the tricky part, where I need some help – I send this URL to someone as a link. That user clicks on the link and I want the web page to open up with the correct panel visible. The problem is, any logic I implement to perform this has to be in the page, and the page has to be loaded, and for the page to be loaded, it has to exist on the server. However, there is no `about.html` on the server. There is only a single page with the panels that are hidden and made visible on demand. How do I do this? *(see update below)*

Of course, one way would be to simply have copies of my page named as `about.html` and `privacy.html` but surely, I can do this much more cleverly, can't I?

How?

**Update:** so, with the magic of Unix, I can create a symbolic link `ln -s index.html about.html` (**index.html** is my actual, existing web page while **about.html** is the page that doesn't exist but has to look like it does) and this does work. When I ask the browser to load `about.html`, it doesn't know any better and loads the page that the web server sends. So, this is the solution, I guess. Any gotchas I've got to watch out for?

Comment: This is something that has to be handled by the server software routing rather than client-side javascript. You might set all routes matching a certain path pattern to point to the same page, then render panels depending on the path variables.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The reason I posted the question was to specifically see if it can be done somehow without creating complexity on the server-side. In the end, if nothing works, I might simply make copies of the same page with different names (as I hinted in my original post), but let's see if the collective mind of SO has some suggestions

Comment: You mention `nothing on the server except a simple web server.` Are you running a local server or just opening a html/js file for the above?

Comment: I am running `nginx` but I specifically want my application to be a 100% client-side app. See the update to my original post for a possible solution

Comment: This might help re: local server config: https://serverfault.com/a/170607/174964 if you're doing it 100% client side you could use Electron if you don't mind the bloat. If you want to keep it as a local browser site, maybe just use hash marks or querystrings in the address `localhost/index#about` to avoid it searching for actual path.